# Applying a function to multiple columns in a list

Tags: python, pandas

Edit: I am a numpty and was df.iloc-ing to wrong columns. The first thing I'd tried worked, but I thought it didn't. Apologies, thank you, case closed.

Solution:

```
def cols_1(x):
    if x == "5: Very important":
        return 5
    if x == "1: Not at all important":
        return 1      
    else:
        return x
```

for c in cols:
df[c] = df[c].apply(cols_1)

I have many columns I want to apply the same function to.

```
cols=['a','b','c','d']

def cols_1(x):
    if x[c]=="5: Very important":
        return 5
    if x[c]== "1: Not at all important":
        return 1      
    else:
        return x

for c in cols:
    df[c]=df[c].apply(cols_1)
```

I've tried many variations of the above, but none is working. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
Other things I've tries

```
def cols_1(x):
    for c in cols:
        if x[c]=="5: Very important":
            return 5
        if x[c]== "1: Not at all important":
            return 1      
        else:
            return x
```

Runs but the output remains the same.

```
def cols_1(x):
    #for c in cols:
        if x=="5: Very important":
            return 5
        if x== "1: Not at all important":
            return 1      
        else:
            return x
        
for c in cols:
    df[c]=df[c].applymap(cols_1)
```

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

```
for c in cols:
    df[c]=df.apply(lambda x: cols_1(x),axis=1)
```

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
for c in cols:
    def cols_1(x):
        if x[c]=="5: Very important":
            return 5
        if x[c]== "1: Not at all important":
            return 1      
        else:
            return x
        df.applymap(cols_1(x))
```

Runs but output remains the same

```
def cols_1(x):
    #for c in cols:
        if x[c]=="5: Very important":
            return 5
        if x[c]== "1: Not at all important":
            return 1      
        else:
            return x
        
for c in cols:
    df[c]=df[c].applymap(cols_1)
```

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'

Comment: What do you mean "none is working"? What happens when you run your code? Do you get an error? If so, please [edit] your question with the full error message. If not, what is the output? Please [edit] your question to include it. Then describe how the output differs from what you want.

Comment: The function doesn't need to use `[c]`. You already did that when you wrote `df[c]`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply replace the strings by the values you need.

```py
# Replace values with .replace()
df[cols] = df[cols].replace(
  {
    '5: Very important':'5',
    '1: Not at all important':'1'
  }
)
```

No need to define your own function or iterate over columns in a loop. Generally speaking, vectorized methods are more efficient than loops.

Comment: Thanks. I get ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: After the edit it runs, but the output doesn't change

Comment: Didn't notice you edited the question. The solution should work now.